# Client Side Code To Capture Calculated Field Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, console-application

I am using C#.Net to query Sharepoint site.  I am able to return all the data I need except ONE field, which the culprit seems to be due to it is a calculated field so it does not "exist" in my query results.
I have calculated field called hours worked, how can I query that field and return the results in my below syntax?

This is how I query:

```
string server = "blahblahblah";
string msn = "14318";
var ctx = new ClientContext(server);
ver web = ctx.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Attendance");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq><Where>";
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                                          item => item,
                                          item => item["recID"],
                                          item => item["MasterID"]));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem li in listItemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(li["recID"]);
    Console.WriteLine(li["MasterID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a huge error in your code

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

that should be

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

it is really possible the "createallitems" won't contain and might remove calculated columns as those are not required for item creation, 
i would also add the fields to the View portion of the CamlQuery

to add fields to the camlquery

```
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Field1"/>
<FieldRef Name="Field2"/>
<FieldRef Name="Field3"/>
</ViewFields>
```

Comment: Interesting.  My syntax executed as expected even with my incorrect code.  Any idea how to pull the data from the calculated field?

Comment: edited to add the reason

Comment: Would I use single quotes to encompass the field names?

Comment: you can use both single quotes or \"

Comment: It has been sitting on my ctx.ExecuteQuery() for 2 minutes now?  I set query to camlQuery.ViewXml = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Field1"/><FieldRef Name="Field2"/><FieldRef Name="Field3"/>
</ViewFields><where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq><Where>";

Comment: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"recID\"/><FieldRef Name=\"MasterID\"/></ViewFields><where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+msn+"</Value></Eq><Where>"

Also be sure that those are the internal names of your columns, you can check it out in your list settings by clicling the column, the last parameter is the internal column name

Comment: but what about the computed column?  It does not have an inernal column name, only a DisplayName?

Comment: on the Url, there's a you'll find "field=<<fieldname">> that's the internal name of your column, that name won't change even after renaming the column

Comment: On the URL? It only is showing the site for the sharepoint list I am viewing.  I capture the other field names from viewing page source

Comment: yeah, those are the same names, but you can click on the column on site settings to check the name

Comment: Upon further examination, it seems to be ignoring the number input in my whwere clause and returning all results.  Any insight into that?